# Organic Group Notifications : Enabling OGN module render adding other category subscriptions dysfunctional

Tags: organic-groups, notifications

I enabled the OG-notifications module to enable notifications for the content being added to a particular group. It is correctly adding the subscriptions for Organic groups.

But, when the other category subscriptions are being added (i.e. Content Types / Thread), error prompts with message "Select existing group" appears. Thus, other subscriptions are not being added.

Any suggestions to set right adding other subscriptions are welcome.